# Changing Header In WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to change a header of an API in wso2 api manager ?
Suppose you have an API with the required header user-key:user-value and you want to change it to backend-key:user-value.

I want to know is this possible  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom sequence you can do this easily as follows.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="header_sequence">
   <property name="user-value" expression="$trp:user-key"/>
   <header name="backend-key" scope="transport" expression="get-property('user-value')"/>
   <property name="user-key" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
</sequence>
```

1. Reads the user key header
2. Adds the backend-key header with the user key header value
3. Deletes the user key header. Otherwise, it passes to the backend.

Comment: Thank you , I have already use this way and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by writing a class mediator also. If there is a request that comes with **backend-key** header, you can get that and set that as the **user-key** header. This can be done by writing a class mediator. You can write the logic inside the mediator. Refer to this documentation https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/adding-a-class-mediator/.